# Android Studio 3.2 stuck installing apk on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

This is new for me for Studio 3.2.  I'll be using an emulator, stopping, coding, running without issue then it fails 'Installing APK'.

Tried different emulators - same sequence - it works for a bit then gets stuck.

Tried restarting emulator - no change.

Tried moving to a different emulator - hmmm, it's working again.   And repeat.

This just started to occur after upgrading to 3.2 - been using Studio for a few years without this kind of issue.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Try Invalidate caches and Restart.

Comment: Are you using signed APK?

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo this is during development phase - no publishing/signed apks.

Comment: This happens not only for emulator, real devices too.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for my after including this definition in my gradle:

```
android {
    ....
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/darwin/libscrypt.dylib'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/freebsd/libscrypt.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/linux/libscrypt.so'
        pickFirst "lib/x86/librealm-jni.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so"
        pickFirst "lib/mips/librealm-jni.so"
        pickFirst "lib/armeabi/librealm-jni.so"
        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/librealm-jni.so"
    }
}
```